# Hosting github releases on private network

Tags: npm, binaryfiles, vpn, node-sass, private-network

I have couple of NPM packages that requires binary files during it's installing process. (For example, during [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) installation scripts, the package requires a binary file that could be found on [node-sass releases page](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.12.0)).

My team is working on private network environment (disconnected from github) and therefore we need to host/serve the binaries privately.

At the moment, we use the `sass_binary_dir` parameter which makes the install script to look for the files in a shared drive that contains the needed binaries.

That method is fine for node-sass but is not working for other packages that requires the real binary repository or another website / proxy but not filesystem location or directory.

I would like to know if there is a recommended way to host the files ? (Something like [Verdaccio](https://verdaccio.org/) but for binary files).
I also thought about fileZilla but it seems as a bit uncomfortable solution.
Writing a server myself could be fine as a temporary solution, but in the future I belive it would have to be maintained by another more organized solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution there was to create a simple API that enables fetching the package over HTTPS / FTP.